# MySQL RDS Performance Insight got stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance-monitoring, amazon-rds

We are using AWS MySQL RDS. Quite recently, we are saw MySQL RDS Performance Insight got stuck with

```
SET `@slave_uuid` = ?
```

Like the following image

[image: Top SQL from RDS Performance Insights]

The second one that follows the above is

```
Use `db_name`
```

As I check from the cloud watch monitoring. All the CPU/IOPS are pretty normal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to trace/solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in MySQL Performance Schema affecting these MySQL versions:

- `>= 5.6.46`
- `>= 5.7.28`
- `>= 8.0.18`

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=961243

It's been over a year, no fix yet: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99039